# Turtlebot android applications - Fuerte

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I installed ROS Fuerte on turtlebot's laptop and apps of Willow garage on my tablet.
I can use and save the map in "Make a Map" application.
When I am trying to run "Map Nav" application the map selection server cannot find a map. I have another turtlebot with ROS electric and I can run all android application very well.

Please help me to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45517/turtlebot-android-applications---fuerte/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With my robot, I had the problem that some launch files were not correct in fuerte.

turtlebot_teleop/app/android_*.launch

For aquiring the map, I had to install ros-fuerte-map-store too. For navigating the map I changed the node type in android_map_nav.launch from map_loader to map_manager

```
-  <node pkg="map_store" type="map_loader" name="map_manager" output="screen"/>
+  <node pkg="map_store" type="map_manager" name="map_manager" output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Fabian Saccilotto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2806/fabian-saccilotto/) with karma: 51 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0